# Libraries for Raspberry Pi cluster

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi, mpi, cluster-computing

my associates and I are making a program that needs to run on a Raspberry PI cluster, and we were wondering if there was a library that we could use to treat the cluster as one big CPU. We looked into the open MPI library, however this treats every core in each Raspberry PI as its own node. (And by the way, I apologize if my vocabulary isn't 100% correct, I'm working on the code more than the cluster itself). The code I am implementing utilizes thread pools, and the number of threads depends on how many cores are available for use. So if instead I could have one node, with 32 cores (we have 8 pis with 4 cores on each of them) instead of 32 nodes, that would make my job a lot easier. Even having 8 nodes, or one for each pi, would be much easier. Please let me know if such a library exists, or if there is a way to do this with MPI. 
Thanks

Comment: Are each Raspberry Pi an individual or is there a single master controller?

Comment: What were the results when you searched the internet?  Software recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.  You may want to try other sites, such as [softwarerecs.se] or SuperUser.